# button is not centered when using jquery append

Tags: jquery, css, append

I wonder why when I  am using CSS - my buttons are horizontally centered and when I am using the same code in `append()` the buttons are aligned to one of the sides.

HTML/CSS code:

```
<div style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
    <button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try1</button>
    <button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try2</button>
</div>
```

and the jquery code:

```
$('#inner_body').append('<div style="margin:auto;display:block;width: 100%;text-align: center">');
$('#inner_body').append('<button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try1</button>');
$('#inner_body').append('<button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try2</button>');
$('#inner_body').append('</div>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append div separately with opening and closing tag like that.

Append it all at once like this

```
$('#inner_body').append('<div style="margin:auto;display:block;width: 100%;text-align: center"><button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try1</button><button id="somebutton" style="margin:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">try2</button></div>');
```

Or add `text-align: center;` to `#inner_body`.

And another solution is to append 'container' div first and then inside it append buttons. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mq6446hj/

Also, you can't have same unique identifiers (id) on multiple elements.
You have `id="somebutton"` for all buttons. Use class instead.